# AWS RDS Postgresql Connect Without Providing Certificate

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I created a new Postgresql instance in AWS RDS with encryption enabled.

I downloaded the rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem to use it in my connection like this (I already enabled rds.force ssl in parameters group):

```
psql -h "rds-endpoint" -p 5432 \
    "dbname=db user=user sslrootcert=rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem sslmode=verify-full"
```

but I discovered that I can still connect to the instance without providing this certificate

```
psql -h "rds-endpoint" -p 5432 "dbname=db user=user"
```

I don't understand why the tutorial says that I need the pem file to work with the instance. I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In the AWS Docs, it is mentioned that:

> You can set the rds.force_ssl parameter value by updating the
>   parameter group for your DB instance. If the parameter group for your
>   DB instance isn't the default one, and the ssl parameter is already
>   set to 1 when you set rds.force_ssl to 1, you don't need to reboot
>   your DB instance. Otherwise, you must reboot your DB instance for the
>   change to take effect

So make sure that you have rebooted your DB instance.

Comment: had the same issue, also after reboot the server, anyway, when quering the sslinfo, select ssl_is_used(); return "t" which means it use ssl, without any pem file